# Hibernate no such filter configured error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to apply a filter on an entity using Hibernate 4.3. My entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="years")
@FilterDef(name="yearFilter", parameters=@ParamDef(name="yearFilterParam", type="string"))
@Filter(name="yearFilter", condition="name = :yearFilterParam")
public class YearEntity {

@Id
private Integer id;

@Column(unique = true, nullable=false)
private String name;

// getters && setters
// constructors
}
```

When I want to enable filter I receive the following error:  *org.hibernate.HibernateException: No such filter configured [yearFilter]*. In my main method I do the following:

```
    Session sessionFilter = HibernateUtilities.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    sessionFilter.beginTransaction();

    //Filter flt = sessionFilter.enableFilter("yearFilter");
    sessionFilter.enableFilter("yearFilter").setParameter("yearFilterParam", "2017");
    Query yearQuery = sessionFilter.createQuery("from YearEntity");
    List<YearEntity> yearList = yearQuery.list();
    for (YearEntity year: yearList){
        System.out.println("Year: " + year.getTs_name());
    }
```

The common mistake I found regarding this error is the that the filter was not define. In my case I defined it using @FilterDef.

How to proper setup a filter?

Comment: why are you enabling filter two times?

 Filter flt = sessionFilter.enableFilter("yearFilter");
    flt .setParameter("yearFilterParam", "2017");

Comment: @Zeromus I wanted to see if the filter is applied. I commented that line

Comment: no sure why it's not working for you, because same code is working for me, plese put here whole stack trace of error

Comment: please refer the https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-data-filter-example-xml-and-annotation/